# Cannot connect to android.com / youtube.com with router on

Tags: dns, wireless-router

Problem is: entering android.com or youtube.com in browser address bar brings up page 'This webpage is not available' (Chromium) or 'Unable to connect to server' (Opera) when my router is online.

Symptoms:

- Said two pages cannot be found;
- ping finds something: ping www.youtube.com / www.android com results with 'unknown host'. Without 'www' there are responses from host-213.189.45.121.ggc.com (213.189.45.121) [youtube] and 46.28.247.108 [android]. Both these IPs entered in browser take me to Google homepage. What?
- said pages work normally when I disconnect router and connect my home PC to network cable from my modem without the router in between.
- everything works normally on my laptop, either connected by cable (with modified MAC) or connected via wifi.

My home setup is as follows:

- net cable from my ISP goes to dlink DIR 501 router; my ISP supports DHCP and checks MAC addresses of connected devices (there is MAC associated with my contract), won't connect to net if MAC is wrong.
- in router configuration I entered MAC of my home PC, set admin password and set up ssid/password for wifi. This is the only configuration I performed, everything else is on standard settings (including DHCP enabled by default).
- my home computer runs Debian GNU/Linux, pretty much up to date, and is connected to router with cable.
- my laptop runs Windows 7 and connects to router via wifi.

Aaaand the question is: what is wrong with my configuration, why these particular two pages cause me problems and what can I do to diagnose the problem and fix it?

Comment: This indicates you should be using a third-party DNS Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to:

- Flush your DNS cache on your linux box (that should do it);
- Try your laptop connected via cable to your router;
- Configure your router to use user-defined DNS servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 from Google, as an example).

Comment: Setting custom DNS addresses helped. My ISP runs DNS in local network, but why does it mess up my setup and why for only a few sites, I still have no idea.

Comment: I don't know your ISP, but I tend to change DNS Servers as soon as I get a new router, since I have had problems with my ISP's DNS server going down somewhat frequently.

If you are wondering why entering the IP Addresses in your browser led you to Google's homepage, it may be because they redirect your requests depending on the domain you are trying to access, and since you didn't give any domain, it redirects to the mothership. :)